# How to make a working url like this: example.com/controller/method/&id=1&cat=2

Tags: codeigniter

How to make a working url like this: using codeigniter

```
example.com/controller/method/&id=1&cat=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the URL Class in Codeigniter

```
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/uri.html
```